# Sum values of one column for each occurrence in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can't seem to find the right phrasing for Googling this question because I get closely similar but not correct answers.

I'm busy with the Titanic dataset and want to sum the number of surviving members in a family. So the dataset looks like this:

`+-------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| PassengerId | Survived |  Surname  | NumSurvived |
+-------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
|           1 |        0 | Braund    |             |
|           2 |        1 | Cumings   |             |
|           3 |        1 | Heikkinen |             |
|           4 |        1 | Futrelle  |             |
|           5 |        0 | Braund    |             |
|           6 |        0 | Moran     |             |
|           7 |        0 | Futrelle  |             |
|           8 |        0 | Braund    |             |
|           9 |        1 | Cumings   |             |
+-------------+----------+-----------+-------------+`

I need to sum the Survived value for each surname in the NumSurvived column like so:

`+-------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| PassengerId | Survived |  Surname  | NumSurvived |
+-------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
|           1 |        0 | Braund    |     0       |
|           2 |        1 | Cumings   |     2       |
|           3 |        1 | Heikkinen |     1       |
|           4 |        1 | Futrelle  |     1       |
|           5 |        0 | Braund    |     0       |
|           6 |        0 | Moran     |     0       |
|           7 |        0 | Futrelle  |     1       |
|           8 |        0 | Braund    |     0       |
|           9 |        1 | Cumings   |     2       |
+-------------+----------+-----------+-------------+`

Comment: @ZackJoubert No problem

Comment: Yes, realised it just now. How do I extract the summed 'Survive' value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
df['NumSurvived']=df.groupby('Surname')['Survived'].transform(lambda x: x.eq(1).sum())
```

print(df)

```
   PassengerId  Survived    Surname  NumSurvived
0            1         0     Braund            0
1            2         1    Cumings            2
2            3         1  Heikkinen            1
3            4         1   Futrelle            1
4            5         0     Braund            0
5            6         0      Moran            0
6            7         0   Futrelle            1
7            8         0     Braund            0
8            9         1    Cumings            2
```